# Encrypt .NET Web.config file for specific environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, encryption, web-config

I just learned the command to encrypt a connection string in my Web.config file.

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" "/MyApp"
```

This command does encrypt Web.config. However, In my app I have a Web.config file for several environments: Web.test.config, Web.production.config, etc. Is it possible to specify which env/config file to encrypt? I tried:

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" "/MyApp/Web.test.config"
```

But this did not work.

Comment: aspnet_regiis is specific to the machine, you can't generate the encryption on your local and push to other environments. You need to create a continuous delivery process to customize this by using targeting machines.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use web.XXX.config because it has to be stored in your source code.  You should be using environment variables (which you can still access via your existing code that reads web.config).

The environment variables can be defined on the server directly and this bypasses your problem, e.g. the production server has different connection string than UAT.

Comment: It really is too late to change this, I have 8 environments so doing a build for a specific environment and letting it grab the web.XXX.config for that env is how I am doing it. Just really wish I could encrypt the config file I want and not the default Web.config

Comment: That's not what I mean.  You have the same web.config in your code, but the environment overrides those values that are environment specific.